Unity cannot create Model types prefab in code
The Unity code creates a prefab of type PrefabAssetType.Model.
I want to create a prefab of type "Model", but I always create a "Regular" type, a Model type, and a model type. It bothers me that the FBX file doesn't have a direct reference relationship
GameObject t_prefabSub = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath\<GameObject\>(path);
t_prefabSub.transform.Reset();
PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(t_prefabSub, s_path);


the model type is assigned because the original asset file is an .fbx file ... the one you create is a GameObject YAML .asset ... you would have to actually go into the FBX file and make your modifications there -> export to FBX rather than just creating a prefab
